# Image Upload Preview Only Works on First Row of table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table with a list of products and each row has an "edit" and "delete" button. When you click edit, a modal will pop up with an edit form including an image box with choose file button.

I want the image to be previewed before uploading.

```
    <div class="imagebox">
        <img id="output" src="../<?php echo $row->images; ?>" height="250" width="250"> 
    </div>

    <div class="choosefile">
        <input id="imageup" accept="image/*" onchange="loadFile(event)" class="choosefile" type="file" name="images">
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Here is the javascript code i added for image preview :

```
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    output.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
    output.onload = function() {
        URL.revokeObjectURL(output.src) // free memory
    }
};
```

But the preview only works on the first row. It doesn't work on any other rows. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: By not duplicating IDs, which I presume you are doing here? IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document.

Comment: how do i do it?

Comment: output is an html tag, I don't think it's a good idea to have a variable with this name..

Comment: okay thanks i changed it but i still don't know how i'd get unique ID

Comment: if there is such a thing you should see it in your browser inspector

Comment: they all have the same id. is there a way to give them all different ids?

Comment: `element.id = "...` or remove ID and use class,...